# VC C++ macro parameters getting executed/evaluated each time used in macro

Tags: c++, macros

I have a macro that checks an error state. If there is an error, it logs the result and returns out of the method.

```
CHECKHR_FAILED_RETURN(hr) if(FAILED(hr)){LOGHR_ERROR(hr); return hr;}
```

The macro is called like this:

```
CHECKHR_FAILED_RETURN(_recordingGraph->StopRecording(&currentFile));
```

However, if the result has indeed `FAILED(hr)`, the method is executed again to perform the `LOGHR_ERROR(hr)`. I see why my StopRecording is getting called twice in case of an error, so my question is...

How do you evaluate the result of a parameter in a macro, but use it multiple times within the same macro?

**UPDATE**:

Based on suggestions below, I changed my macros to the following.

```
#define CHECKHR_FAILED_RETURN(hr) do { \
    HRESULT result = hr; \
    if(FAILED(result)) \
    { \
        LOGHR_ERROR(result); \
        return result; \
    } \
} while (false);

#define CHECKHR_FAILED(hr) do { \
    HRESULT result = hr; \
    if(FAILED(result)) \
    { \
        LOGHR_ERROR(result); \
        return true; \
    } \
    else \
    { \
        return false; \
    } \
} while (false);
```

Comment: something something, macros are evil, make a function, something else (on a more serious note, im not sure thats easily feasible, if  at all)

Comment: Can you post code, some of us can't view images.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to do error checking with a macro. You might consider a `try`-`catch` block.

Comment: It would be better if you assign the result to a local variable. Otherwise it is hard to read and debug.

Comment: Instead of macros and return values, use functions and exceptions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for that edit on my answer, I haven't used macros in a while and forgot that little tidbit.

Comment: I have to use macros, because the logging part of it uses __LINE__, __METHOD__, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one commenter says, prefer a function to a macro in every place where it's possible. In this case it's not possible, since you want to embed a `return` into the code.

You can do an assignment to a temporary variable within the macro and use it instead of calling the parameter multiple times.

```
#define CHECKHR_FAILED_RETURN(hr) do{ HRESULT hr2=hr; if(FAILED(hr2)) {LOGHR_ERROR(hr2); return hr2; }}while(false)
```

The `do` loop is an idiom ensuring that the macro can be used in an `if`-`else` just like a function call. With C++11 and onwards you can alternatively use a lambda expression.

Comment: I went down this wrote, but used "\" to make things a little more clear. Check the update to my answer.

Comment: @PaulKnopf: much of the purpose of the `do` is to be able to write `if( blahblah ) MACRO(); else { stuff; }`. That fails when the macro ends in a semicolon. Because the two semicolons then denote an empty statement after the `if`, so that the `else` becomes disconnected.